# Compare two files: lines present in one, not in the other, by one column comparison

Tags: text-processing, columns, join, file-comparison

I need to compare 2 files. Column 1 is the same in both files. Column 2 is what I want to compare: I want all lines in file 1 that are not in file 2 when comparing column 2. Column 3 is different in both files, even for lines where column 1 and 2 are identical. I cannot remove column 3, because as an output I want the lines from file 1 including this column.

Here is an example:

**File 1**

```
21  12340   3
21  12341   7
21  12342   2
21  12343   89
21  12349   7
```

**File 2**

```
21  12340   55
21  12341   7
21  12343   89
21  12344   7
21  12346   88
21  12347   3
21  12348   37
```

My output would be:

```
21  12342   2
21  12349   7
```

Answer (score 8):

`join` requires that the files be presorted, as they are in the esample's args to `join`), so if you need to manintain the sequence ot the *output*, it would need different approach. Note, it doesn't try to keep the width of the original field spacing.

```
join -1 2 -2 2 -v 1 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

*output*

```
21 12342 2
21 12349 7
```

Answer (score 6):

One `awk` solution:

```
awk '
    FNR == NR {
        data[ $2 ] = 1;
        next;
    }
    FNR < NR {
        if ( ! ($2 in data) ) {
            print $0;
        }
    }
' file2 file1
```

Result:

```
21  12342   2
21  12349   7
```

Comment: Good +1... btw, you don't need the `FNR < NR`, because of the preceding `next`... also, you don't need the array **value** assignment. Defining the array's index is enough `data[ $2 ];`, and runse notably faster without it.

Answer (score 3):

Using Python from the bash shell:

```
paddy$ python -c 'import sys
with open(sys.argv[2]) as f: file2col2 = {line.split()[1] for line in f}
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f: print("".join(line for line in f 
                                           if line.split()[1] not in file2col2))
' file1.tmp file2.tmp
21  12342   2
21  12349   7

paddy$
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `egrep` and `awk`:

```
egrep -v -f <(awk '{printf "^%s[ ]+%s[ ]+\n", $1, $2}' file2) file1
```

The `awk` bit inside `<()` generates patterns based on the contents of `file2`. The `egrep` uses these patterns to match lines in `file1`, with `-v` inverting the matching, printing only the lines that don't match.