# Compare three files: lines present in all of them using column comparison

Tags: shell, awk, files, grep

I have three files `2d.tsv`, `3d.tsv`, `4d.tsv`, and they are of the same format (same number of columns with the same data type, but with different numbers of rows).

I want to select rows that are present in all files by comparing column 3 and writing three new files, `2d_new.tsv`, `3d_new.tsv`, `4d_new.tsv`, that is, I want for the three new files to have the same number of rows and maintaining their original first and second columns according to the remaining rows. Could you please help me how to do this?

**Sample Input:**

`2d.tsv`

```
0.1 0.22 gene1
0.3 0.1 gene2
0.5 0.33 gene3
0.3 0.44 gene5
0.9 0.3 gene6
```

`3d.tsv`

```
0.4 0.5 gene2
0.6 0.1 gene3
0.1 0.99 gene4
0.01 0.44 gene5
```

`4d.tsv`

```
0.03 0.11 gene1
0.33 0.34 gene2
0.54 1 gene3
0.41 0.44 gene4
0.44 0.45 gene5
0.11 0.89 gene6
```

**Desired Output:**

`2d_new.tsv`

```
0.3 0.1 gene2
0.5 0.33 gene3
0.3 0.44 gene5
```

`3d_new.tsv`

```
0.4 0.5 gene2
0.6 0.1 gene3
0.01 0.44 gene5
```

`4d_new.tsv`

```
0.33 0.34 gene2
0.54 1 gene3
0.44 0.45 gene5
```

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I've tried to adapt what was being discussed in the topic [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204549/compare-three-files-lines-present-in-one-but-not-in-the-other-using-column-com?rq=1), including instances of cut and awk suggested there, but I could not adapt it to my case since I don't know how to write three different files in just a command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure there is some superstar who will come up with a stunning one shot `awk` solution but here is a sledgehammer.

Assuming that the files are all nicely sorted on the key in column 3 (if not you will need to sort them with `sort -k 3 file` first).

```
join -j 3 2d.tsv 3d.tsv | join -1 1 -2 3 - 4d.tsv > tmp
awk '{print $2, $3, $1}' tmp > 2d_new.tsv
awk '{print $4, $5, $1}' tmp > 3d new.tsv
awk '{print $6, $7, $1}' tmp > 4d_new.tsv
```

The last 3 lines can be combined

```
awk '{ print $2, $3, $1 > "2d_new.tsv"; print $4 $5, $1 > "3d_new.tsv"; print $6, $7, $1 > "4d_new.tsv" }' tmp
```

And if you are bent on a one liner to avoid the `tmp` file then just `|` the `join` to the `awk`

Comment: It worked like a glove! Thanks a lot! By the way, I've edited my question because it was supposed to be 3 columns instead of 4.

Comment: Answer edited to match the post,,,,,